# Where can I find the source code of the last version (3.24) of scrbook.cls?

Tags: titles, koma-script, scrbook

I would like to redefine the `\@maketitle` command of `scrbook`. For this reason I need the source code of `scrbook` class. I don't have Miktex or Texlive installed on my computer, I use only sharelatex.

I know that it is possible to use `\show` or `\meaning` to get the definitions, but I need an output showing also the indentations.

Comment: A good start: https://ctan.org/pkg/scrbook?lang=en.  At that page there is a zip file download.  In the zip file: `tex\latex\koma-script\scrbook.cls`.  V3.24 confirmed.

Comment: There really is no need to develop a  new documentclass for a thesis. If you want to create a titlepag of your own, look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage/210280#210280 and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in my comment,

A good source and always my initial go-to place is CTAN.  For `scrbook`, try `ctan.org/pkg/scrbook?lang=en`. At that page there is a TDS archive, `koma-script.tds.zip` file download. In the zip file subdirectory, you will find: `tex\latex\koma-script\scrbook.cls`. V3.24 confirmed.

The definition of `\@maketitle` is

```
\newcommand*{\@maketitle}{%
  \global\@topnum=\z@
  \setparsizes{\z@}{\z@}{\z@\@plus 1fil}\par@updaterelative
  \ifx\@titlehead\@empty \else
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
      \usekomafont{titlehead}{\@titlehead\par}%
    \end{minipage}\par
  \fi
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
    \ifx\@subject\@empty \else
      {\usekomafont{subject}{\@subject \par}}%
      \vskip 1.5em
    \fi
    {\usekomafont{title}{\huge \@title \par}}%
    \vskip .5em
    {\ifx\@subtitle\@empty\else\usekomafont{subtitle}\@subtitle\par\fi}%
    \vskip 1em
    {%
      \usekomafont{author}{%
        \lineskip .5em%
        \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
          \@author
        \end{tabular}\par
      }%
    }%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\usekomafont{date}{\@date \par}}%
    \vskip \z@ \@plus 1em
    {\usekomafont{publishers}{\@publishers \par}}%
    \ifx\@dedication\@empty \else
      \vskip 2em
      {\usekomafont{dedication}{\@dedication \par}}%
    \fi
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 2em
}%
```

Comment: One more question, how to redefine it ?  \renewcommand*\@maketitle or \def\@maketitle seem not to work

Comment: @BxlAdil The `@` character is a special charcter.  In normal documents, it is considered an "other" symbol and cannot be part of a macro name.  In classes and styles, it is considered a "letter"  and can be part of a macro name.  To overcome this limitation in your document, there is `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, which change the `\catcode` of `@` to 11 and 12, respectively.  Thus, place `\makeatletter` before your redefinition of `\@maketitle` and `\makeatother` after its redefinition.

Comment: @BxlAdil See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do

Comment: Actually I used many times these commands. But still I don't know why it is not working, please check this MWE in overleaf https://www.overleaf.com/13690295wtvwgtxrvkwm#/52962103/    normaly the title should be colored in red and a smal word must be added in the bottom.

Comment: @BxlAdil No reason jumps to mind as to why the change does not take.  I would say, however, that it is a large complex class.

Comment: @BxlAdil It would appear, with your MWE, that `\if@titlepage` is set true, and so that block of code executed by `\maketitle` bypasses the call the `\@maketitle`.

Comment: @BxlAdil ...so look for the part of the `\maketitle` definition that between the `\begin` and `\end` of the environment `{titlepage}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72889/discussion-between-bxladil-and-steven-b-segletes).

Answer (score 2):

As you use ShareLaTeX, you must patch the `scrbook.cls` provided by ShareLaTeX.

Compile the following document on ShareLaTeX to get the correct source (96 pages with colors):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\newcommand*{\noaccsupp}[1]{\BeginAccSupp{ActualText={}}#1\EndAccSupp{}}

\title{\texttt{scrbook.cls} listing on ShareLaTeX}
\author{Paul Gaborit}
\date{February 2018}
\lstdefinestyle{latex}{
  fancyvrb=true,
  language=[LaTeX]TeX,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
  commentstyle=\color{red!50!black}\itshape,
  stringstyle=\ttfamily\color{green!50!black},
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray}\noaccsupp,
  stepnumber=1,
  numbersep=5pt,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  %backgroundcolor=\color{white},
  frame=leftline,
  rulecolor=\color{gray!30},
  fontadjust=true,
  aboveskip=0pt,
  belowskip=0pt,
  emphstyle=\color{red},
  keepspaces=true,
  flexiblecolumns=true,
  xleftmargin=1.2em,
}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\lstinputlisting[style=latex]{scrbook.cls}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, I was going to suggest this excellent idea. Basically if TeX can use `scrbook` then it can find it, so you can just use TeX to typeset it. (BTW your code compiles for me on ShareLaTeX only if I replace `/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbook.cls` with just `scrbook.cls`.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR "_Your wishes are orders_" (I removed the path).

Answer (score 0):

You asked the wrong question, which happens quite frequently on tex.sx. You are (probably) a kind of newbie to LaTeX and you'd like to do something with the title of your article / report / book.

Please ask a new question about what you want to achieve in the end.

Hacking into a mainline package like the KOMA-script bundle probably is neither worth the effort, nor the way to go. Many many layouts can be realised without that. Just ask an add an MWE.

Comment: @ Keks Dose I started to use latex in 2011.

Comment: And I'm writing my own document class for my thesis

Comment: @BxlAdil Well, after reading this and the other answer and comments, I stick to my advise. Usually a thesis is challenging enough without maintaining a documentclass based on KOMA-script. Either a thesis, or a documentclass. Good luck!